# Referencing another cell twice in a Google Sheet formula returned error

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, split, flatten, textjoin

I want to check where - in a specified range - does a value exist in a Google Sheet. If I already know the column, I would use the "Match()" function to get the row number. But let's say if I still want to get a number for the column, and use the Match() function again, I wasn't able to.
In the match function, I wanted to use a dynamic value like "Sheet1!E3" to specify the row I'm searching for, but it didn't work.
[Here is the sheet to illustrate the idea.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1e102YbYYT6FtbxBf7gN_FOKWhu0BTXhVmMt7YZjZibQ/edit?usp=sharing)
Why is that? In a case like this, if I want to use the dynamic value twice - Sheet1!E3:Sheet1!E3, what should I do instead?

Thanks!

See the test sheet linked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

delete E4. use in E3:

```
=INDEX(FLATTEN(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(, 1, IF(E2=A2:B17, ROW(A2:B17)&"​"&COLUMN(A2:B17), )), "​")))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much @player0! This is exactly what's going to help! ----- However, I tried to understand how it works but couldn't really.. any relevant documentations on these you would recommend me read to understand better? I tried to understand it piece by piece, but I got all errors when I dissected them up. For example, I tried "=IF(E2=A2:B17, ROW(A2:B17)&"​"&COLUMN(A2:B17), )" and wanted to see what just this would return but got error already.

Comment: @PeiranYu for processing arrays/multi-cell ranges you always need ARRAYFORMULA wrapping. try to run it like: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(E2=A2:B17, ROW(A2:B17)&"_"&COLUMN(A2:B17), ))`